# How to get the value from model to controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, controller

**model**

This is my model.using last query I get value in the model,but I don't get the value in the controller

```
class Login_model extends CI_Model {
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function email()
    {
        $this->db->select('email');
        $this->db->from('change_password');
        $result=$this->db->get();
        return $result;
    }
}
```

**controller**

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function checking()
    {
        $email=$this->input->post('email');
        $this->load->model('login_model');
        $dbemail=$this->login_model->email();
        echo $dbemail;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you `field` name is `email` and `table` name is `change_password`

Comment: are you fetching all emails or only single one? have you tried `print_r($dbemail)`???

Comment: yes,table name & field name  is correct

Comment: @Arthi You need to update your code as answered.

Comment: Please update your question what you actually want??@Arthi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CI is a **MVC** Framework. So you need to Command from Controller and get data from the models and finely you need to pass them to view. This is a best Practice

**Controller**

```
function checking()
 {
 $email=$this->input->post('email');
 $this->load->model('login_model');
 $data['dbemail']=$this->login_model->email();// assign your value to CI variable  
 $this->load->view('home', $data); //passing your value to view
 }
```

**Model**

```
public function email()
 {
   $query = $this->db->query("SELECT email FROM change_password");
   $result = $query->result_array();
   return $result;
 }
```

**View**

Extra Knowledge

1. View will be create under `View` folder/ **Ex** im using view name
   as `home.php`
2. you can use your own stylings(its also created as normal html page.)

   ```
    foreach ( $dbemail as $new_dbemail )
      {
         echo $new_dbemail['database_field'];//in here you can get your table header. 
        //Ex if your table has name field and you need to sho it you can use $new_dbemail['name'] 
       }
   ```